# getJSON and Internet Explorer 9 returns a .js file?

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer, getjson

So I made a script that takes data off a facebook wall and posts it on a website. This script works perfectly fine in Firefox and chrome and on my phone so I guess safari too. As usual though, Internet Explorer has decided to be a funt about it.

So, I use the getJSON call to access a facebook URL and return the data. I then take the parts of the data I need and place it into html code which is then sent back and displayed on the website. I would like to be able to use this on Internet Explorer too obviously. Hopefully somebody can take a look and spot how to fix it (or improve my code :D). I don't use Javascript / JQuery all that often and can do some basic stuff with it but when it comes to fixing issues like this I get lost quickly. Ill post script below. Thanks

**Update**

so I added a error callback onto the script to check what the problem was and it gives a No Transport error in Internet Explorer but none in any other browser. Anybody know of a fix for this ?

```
var myNewData, myOldData;

function fbstream() {
  var restart_counter, url, time, date, html, post_count;
  url = "https://graph.facebook.com/xyz/posts?limit=7&access_token=121936661313114|YX63lMRU9wc8RDP8MMSs9keT3fQ";
  $.getJSON(url, function (json) {
    html = "<div class='fbfeed'>";
    if (json.data[0] === undefined && restart_counter < 5) {
      fbstream();
      restart_counter += 1;
    } else if (json.data[0] === undefined && restart_counter === 5) {
      $('.facebookfeed').html("Problem loading Facebook content");
    } else {
      post_count = 0;
      if (myNewData !== undefined) {
        myOldData = myNewData;
      }
      myNewData = json.data[0].id;
      if (myOldData !== myNewData || myOldData === undefined) {
        $.each(json.data, function (i, fb) {
        if (fb.message !== undefined) {
          post_count += 1;
          date = fb.created_time.substring(0, 10).split("-", 3).reverse().join("-", 3);
          time = fb.created_time.substring(11, 19);
          html += "<div class='fbpost'><div class='dateandtime'>" + date + " at " + time + "</div><div class='fbmsg'>" + fb.message + "</div>";
          if (fb.picture !== null) {
            html += "<div class='fbimg'><img src='" + fb.picture + "' class='center' /></div>";
          }
          html += "</div>";
          if (post_count === 3) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
      html += "</div>";
      $('.facebookfeed').html(html);
    }
  }
});
restart_counter = 0;
}
setInterval(function () {
  fbstream();
}, 300000);
```

I tried to format it as best I could to make it readable. Its possible that parts are slightly off.

As the title mentions, Internet Explorer returns a file named posts.js when I visit the url that getJSON queries. In firefox and chrome that url just opens in a new page with a bunch of json data.

I can post an example of the json data if required

Here is an item from post.js as requested. There are more but I just took one for something to reference

```
{
"data": [
  {
     "id": "3688793151660_5429280924451",
     "from": {
        "category": "Energy/utility",
        "name": "xyz",
        "id": "3688793151660"
     },
     "message": "And after !",
     "picture": "http://photos-h.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/123.jpg",
     "link": "http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=282413452&set=a.368887806484148.88464.368879353151660&type=1&relevant_count=1",
     "icon": "http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yz/r/StEh33hPvjk.gif",
     "privacy": {
        "value": ""
     },
     "type": "photo",
     "status_type": "added_photos",
     "object_id": "542928413452",
     "application": {
        "name": "Facebook for iPhone",
        "namespace": "fbiphone",
        "id": "66268379"
     },
     "created_time": "2013-03-07T15:24:00+0000",
     "updated_time": "2013-03-07T15:24:00+0000",
     "likes": {
        "data": [
           {
              "name": "removed",
              "id": "1000392350"
           },
           {
              "name": "removed",
              "id": "721372"
           }
        ],
        "count": 2
     },
     "comments": {
        "count": 0
     }
  },
  "paging": {
  "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/3688793151660/posts?limit=7&access_token=121936661313114|YX63lMRU9wc8RDP8MMSs9keT3fQ&since=1362669840&__previous=1",
  "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/3688793151660/posts?limit=7&access_token=121936661313114|YX63lMRU9wc8RDP8MMSs9keT3fQ&until=1358410924"
   }
}
```

Formatting is a little messy and some ids / names have been edited / removed

Comment: What content type are you getting with your response? It should be application/json and not text/plain.

Comment: How do i find out? the response starts out with {
   "data": [
      { but formatted if that helps

Comment: What are the contents of post.js? (we just need the first 30 characters or so)

Comment: ill update my post one moment

Comment: The json looks fine. The only reason I asked about the content type is that IE will try to download plain text files and not render them to the browser response directly if the content type isn't set properly in the response header.

Comment: is there a way to set the response header with the getJSON method? might be worth forcing it to the correct way just incase.

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed.

Added the following line of code which I found on this site after some googling about "No Transport" error in Internet Explorer

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
```